# Bootstrap Carousel does not show

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

For some unidentifiable reason, my Bootstrap carousel is not showing anything but its image contents, no carousel interface whatsoever. All other functions in bootstrap.js and jQuery seems to have loaded fine when I messed with the console. I also tried this in other browsers to no effect. I included my implementations just in case I did anything wrong there.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B"
                crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gaegu" rel="stylesheet">
            <title>King City</title>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div id="masterContainer" class="container-fluid">
     <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="assets/images/150-2 copy.jpeg" alt="First Slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/150-3 copy.jpeg" alt="Second Slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/150-4 copy.jpeg" alt="Third Slide">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="assets/images/150-5 copy.jpeg" alt="Fourth Slide">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UQBr.png)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arv433/nkp5gs8w/)

Comment: I changed the jQuery library to the uncompressed version, the same issue still persists

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle link to the code, will try to help out with a possible solution.

Comment: I just added my fiddle, sorry if it seems messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is correct Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gaegu" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>King City</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="masterContainer" class="container-fluid">
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/150-2.jpeg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/150-3.jpeg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/150-4.jpeg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/images/150-5.jpeg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

N.B: Remove the space and the word "copy" from your image name.

[***LIVE DEMO:***](https://codepen.io/codegiant04/pen/MBjVdL)

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo in Stack Overflow, the tags in my IDE are correct. I don't have any bugs in my console.

Comment: is that ok now?

Comment: oh.. no.. got it. You have included bootstrap 3 js instead of bootsrtap4 and class missing. I'm giving you the original.

Comment: I found it... The Bootstrap .css file is missing!  In fact, it's there but it's the Bootstrap 4 one... Replace it by `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">` --- So in addition of @Codegiant's answer... It works.

Comment: Here is a [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/bjwvLo?editors=1011) working.

Comment: check the update of your complete code.. just updated

Comment: @ArvinZojaji select my answer plz if it's helpful. thanks